# Распарсить json в python

Tags: python, json

```
import requests
import json

# Получаем HTML-код страницы
url = 'https://www.geooptic.ru/product/lasernyi-skanner-trimble-x7-kit-with-t10x'
response = requests.get(url).text
#html = response.content

# Ищем строку с информацией о файлах
start = 'files:['
end = '],'
start_index = response.index(start) + len(start)
end_index = response.index(end, start_index)
files_str = response[start_index:end_index]
print(files_str)
```

out:

```
{file_name:"obzor-skanerov-trimble.pdf",name:"Сравнение сканеров TRIMBLE X7, TX6, TX8 и тахеометра SX10 (2019 год)",type_id:eW},{file_name:"Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet.pdf",name:"Trimble T10x tablet_Datasheet",type_id:4},{file_name:"Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12.pdf",name:"Сравнение приборов Trimble 2022 X7 X12 SX12",type_id:eW}
```

## я хочу его распарсить:

```
# Извлекаем информацию о файлах
files_info = json.loads('[' + files_str + ']')

# Выводим результат
for file_info in files_info:
    print(f"{file_info['name']} : {file_info['file_name']}")'''
```

## у меня выходить ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: JSONDecodeError
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
  File "/home/artddss/python/em/de.py", line 18, in <module>
    files_info = json.loads('[' + files_str + ']')
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что строка `files_str` не является валидным `JSON-объектом`. В `JSON-формате` строки должны быть заключены в двойные кавычки, а не в одинарные.

**Первый вариант решения:**
Замените строку `files_info = json.loads('[' + files_str + ']')` на `files_info = json.loads('[' + files_str.replace("'", '"') + ']')`.

**Второй вариант решения:**
Делаем следующую конструкцию

```python
files_str = files_str.replace("'", '"')
files_info = json.loads('[' + files_str + ']')
```

Comment: как сделать где нет кавычек: пример "name":cL,", добавить кавычки?

Comment: Это, конечно, частный случай, но можно заменить значение с помощью `re.sub`.  А именно: `json_str = re.sub(r':', r':"', json_str)`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что параметры словаря должна быть заключены в двойные кавычки - в вашем случаи таково нет. Для таково типа данных придется писать свой парсер.