# ошибки в json python

Tags: python, json

## Добрый вечер

я парсю сотни json файлов, но много попадаются кривые json,

```
{"name":"Максимальная дальность","unit":cH,"value":"invalid_key"}
```

подскажите пожалуйста как добавить кавычки, что было так?

```
{"name":"Максимальная дальность","unit":"cH","value":"invalid_key"}
```

Comment: Главное, чтобы двоеточия и запятые не попадались внутри строк данных, а то всё сложно станет )

Answer (score 0):

Работаешь сначала как со строкой, т.е. парсишь на куски - от запятой до двоеточия.

Т.е. делишь файл на:

- **от** "{" **до** ":"
- **от** ":" **до** ","
- **от** "," **до** ":"
- **от** ":" **до** "}"

В каждом куске проверяешь на наличие кавычек.
Есть есть одинарные кавычки - сразу замена на двойные.
Если число кавычек не равно 2 - значит какая-то фигня - и вот тут нужно оценить куда добавить кавычку.

Напишешь такую функцию - и всё будет в порядке)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь придется использовать регулярные выражения (не уверен) или писать свой парсер. Я написал парсер на основе коментария от @Kraftsov.
Вот код (переменная js это ваш json):

```
out = [i.split(':') for i in js[1:-1].replace('"', '').split(',')]
```

**EDIT:** Нашел решение [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1500708/490099). Регулярные выражения можно использовать таким видом:

```
json_str = re.sub(r':', r':"', json_str)
```

А `json_str` - это ваш json.